# Why does replacement work in first line only

Tags: javascript, replace

Why does the jquery replacment work in first line only?

```js
var el = $('#X');
el.html(el.html().replace("&", "%26"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Line 1: <span id="X"><a href="http://www.www.com/test&test1"></a></span>
Line 2: <span id="X"><a href="http://www.www.com/test&test2"></a></span>
```

Comment: You sure that's the problem or are there multiple instances of `&`? A string used as needle will only have first instance replaced

Comment: Oj ok so it only replaces the first line. I will edit my question if possible.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  I smell an XY Problem here that can easily be fixed with `escape()` or `encodeURI()`.

Comment: id attributes must be unique in valid html.

Comment: You're also missing `</a>` tags.

Comment: There must be a way to replace this code `var el = $('#X');` with something else but what? I can't change element id.

Answer (score -1):

instead of html you use text() like below, it will work.

```js
var el = $('#X');
el.html(el.text().replace("&", "%26"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="X">test & test1</span>
```

Its because the html string returned is encoded, and you need to decode it before replacing.

Comment: Thats because & gets converted to "&amp;" in html.

Comment: You can try it on this page itself in devtools, its working at my end.

Comment: hmm ok understood now.